# Creating Product Sets on Facebook using Graph API or Javascript SDK

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-business-sdk

I am trying to create product sets from an existing catalogue on facebook. I was able to use nodejs-facebook-business-sdk well so far to fetch the catalogueID, the product ids and other fields from facebook. I wanted to move a step forward but keep failing on the nodejs-facebook-business-sdk.

This is the nodejs-facebook-business-sdk code:

```
const api = bizSdk.FacebookAdsApi.init(accessToken);
const business = new bizSdk.Business(businessId);
const catalogs = await new Business(businessId).getOwnedProductCatalogs();
const catalogId = catalogs[0].id;
//works well upto this point and fails below this point
const productSet = await new ProductCatalog(catalogId).createProductSet(
{},
{[ProductSet.Fields.name]: set_id}
);
```

Hence, I decided to try out the GraphAPI and then use that URL to insert my data into a POST URL. I am however now stuck again because I am using the below JSON-encoded URL for the fields:
`filter%3D%7B%22product_item_id%22%3A%7B%22eq%22%3A%5B%22prod_id1%22%2C%22prod_id2%22%5D%7D%7D`

In doing this I am getting this error below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Product set with the same filters already exists",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10803,
    "error_data": {
      "product_set_id": "398669932127803"
    },
    "error_subcode": 1798073,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Duplicate product set already exists",
    "error_user_msg": "Error when you try to create a product set when a product set with a duplicate filter already exists",
    "fbtrace_id": "App-C-nBvtS4szCeo6dSS8_"
  }
}
```

Searching for these error codes yields nothing. I tried reporting a bug but they want me to post on their community platform. Trying to post there also fails because apparently my post doesnt meet their guidelines for posting.

Comment: Not sure why you would start searching for any error codes, when it already tells you in plain English, _"Product set with the same filters already exists"_ - are you disagreeing with that response, or what exactly is the issue supposed to be?

Comment: @CBroe Im sorry, I think I didn't finish the problem description entirely. The product set its referring to is one created automatically by Facebook and it contains all my products. This isnt what I want, the filter is only applicable to certain product_item_ids.

Comment: If it thinks your "filtered" product set was identical to the unfiltered, general one - then that might indicate that it did not _take_ your filter parameter to begin with.

Comment: Thats what concerned me since the filter in the automatically generated product sets has all the item ids, while the one I am sending only has two. Yet it isnt being posted. I even tried another unique identifier with an and operation to the request I am sending but this fails too.

Comment: Is there any documentation for that `createProductSet` method available anywhere?

Comment: None that I could find. I went through the methods that autofilled on VSCode for `ProductCatalog` class and `createProductSet` seemed to be the one that could fit my usecase best.